# Is this synchronized lock order work?

Tags: java, locking, deadlock, synchronized

I written a game and it some time get into deadlock, after search google about the problem it seem lock order method maybe work so I go here to make sure it will be no problem.

There will be at most three user interact to each other: A, B and C.

Actions are attack, recapture, and rescue

Example: A attack B, B recapture from A, A rescue B from C

Each of user had an unique id

Interact between two user seem work if I order synchronized on user object ordered by their id desc or asc. but will it work with three user in rescue action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided all locks are acquired in the same order, you will be safe from dead lock. So as long as "A rescue B from C" acquires locks in the order A then B then C, and "B rescue C from A" **also** acquires locks in the order A then B then C, you should be OK.